# Método sendo chamado várias vezes no evento change de um p:ajax

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces

Tenho uma tabela com um `p:inputText` com um `p:ajax` dentro, o mesmo possui o evento `change`, quando preencho esse `inputText` com um valor uma consulta e algumas validações são realizadas. O problema é que quando eu colo um valor dentro desse `inputText` (ctrl+v) o método é chamado duas vezes. Se eu digito o valor no `inputText` ao invés de cola-lo o método funciona da maneira correta, ou seja, é chamado apenas uma vez.

**xhtml**:

```
<p:inputText id="codigoFunInput" label="Código"
   mask="9?999999999" maxlength="7" slotChar=""
   readonly="#{!item.novoFuncionario}"
   style="width:100%;text-align:" value="#{item.codigo}">
   <p:ajax event="change"
      listener="#{mbean.carregaNomeFuncionario(item)}"
      process="@this" partialSubmit="true"
      update="dataTableResponsaveis, :formTopo:topoMessage" />
</p:inputText>
```

O que pode estar "estragando" essa requisição ajax? Tenho outros eventos ajax na tela, porém servem pra outras coisas.

Obs: Na tela também tenho alguns decorates na tela também, não sei isso pode influenciar.

Comment: Provavelmente o evento atributo event="change" está sendo disparado no keyUp do teclado, como ctrl + v são duas teclas, logo serão 2 eventos (não tenho nenhum projeto pequeno agora para testar). Você já tentou usar o atributo delay do p:ajax ? tente algo como delay="1000" e veja se funciona.

Comment: Vou tentar, eu acho que resolvi alterando pra blur e tratando ele, mas se der certo no change é melhor

Comment: @wryel Funcionou, pode responder a pergunta :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provavelmente o evento do atributo **event="change"** está sendo disparado no keyUp do teclado, como ctrl + v são duas teclas, logo serão 2 eventos. Teste usar o atributo delay do p:ajax

```
<p:ajax delay="1000" event="change"  
  listener="#{mbean.carregaNomeFuncionario(item)}"
  process="@this" partialSubmit="true"
  update="dataTableResponsaveis, :formTopo:topoMessage" />
```